# Update enpoint based on datepicker selection (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I'm trying to update the parameters of an endpoint based on the date picker selection. I'm working on ReactJS and DatePicker for React
For example something like this

```
const res = await axiosConfig.get(`/${startTimeStamp}/posts`)
```

But I'm getting an error `undefined startTimeStamp`

How I should retrieve this?

This is my code:

```
const MainCalendar = (props) => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

    //--- Start
    const minDate = () => {
        const dateStart = new Date(startDate)
        dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate() - 1);
        dateStart.setHours(23, 0, 0, 0);
        // TS
        const startTimeStamp = moment(dateStart).format("x")
        console.log('TS', startTimeStamp)
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        loadData()
    }, [])

    const loadData = async () => {
        const res = await axiosConfig.get(`/${startTimeStamp}/posts`)
        console.log('dbg1', startTimeStamp)
        setData(res.data)
        setLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            {
                isLoading ? <Loader />
                    : (
                                <DatePicker
                                    selected={startDate}
                                    onChange={(date) => {setStartDate(date); minDate()}}

                                />
                    )}
        </>
    );
};

export default MainCalendar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `startTimeStamp` is a constant which is defined inside `minDate` function. constants are block scoped. They will be available only inside the block that they were defined in.

An ideal approach would be to define it as a state variable.

```
const MainCalendar = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [startTimeStamp, setStartTimeStamp] = useState(null);

  //--- Start
  const minDate = () => {
    const dateStart = new Date(startDate);
    dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate() - 1);
    dateStart.setHours(23, 0, 0, 0);
    // TS
    setStartTimeStamp(moment(dateStart).format("x"));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  const loadData = async () => {
    const res = await axiosConfig.get(`/${startTimeStamp}/posts`);
    console.log("dbg1", startTimeStamp);
    setData(res.data);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={(date) => {
            setStartDate(date);
            minDate();
          }}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MainCalendar;
```

Comment: Thanks. That make sense but     console.log("dbg1", startTimeStamp) is keeping null even when the function is calling properly onChange

Comment: @Rolanda add `startTimeStamp` as a dependency array in `useEffect`

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you. You mean this: 

`useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
startTimeStamp; 
  }, []);`

Comment: @Rolanda, Not like that. I couldn't update the answer due to pending edits in SO. You'll need to update the code like this -  `useEffect(() => {     loadData();     }, [startTimeStamp]);`

Comment: That's amazing!! Thank you!! I'll need to investigate why the console.log for the TS inside the function is different than console.log TS in loaddata (dbg1) but I guess that is a different problem